# How to write a recursive query for a self referencing table and junction table (duh)

Tags: sql, sqlite

## 1. Diagram

I have a table entity that references itself. Since it's a 1-M relationship, I created a junktion table `relation entity`.

[image]

## 2. Table Entity

```
TABLE ENTITY (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_ENTITY, wiki_title TEXT);
```

#### 2.1 Sample

```
Id   |ID_ENTITY|  wiki_title   
19127|m.06w4why|Sterling_Hill_Historic_District
19128|m.017ym9|Saint_John_County,_New_Brunswick
19129|m.0jl0r_0|Sheshnag_Lake
```

---

## 3. Relation_entity

```
CREATE TABLE RELATION_ENTITE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ID_SOURCE TEXT, ID_DESTINATION TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(ID_SOURCE) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID_ENTITE), FOREIGN KEY(ID_DESTINATION) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID_ENTITE));
```

#### 3.1 Sample

As you can see in the following sample `m.06w4why` has a relation with three other entities, namely: `m.01x73`, `m.0rg75` and `m.0rg9n`.

```
ID   |id source| id_destination
119647|m.06w4why|m.01x73|
119648|m.06w4why|m.0rg75|
119649|m.06w4why|m.0rg9n|
119650|m.06w4why|m.05gk2h0|

119651|m.017ym9|m.074r0|
119652|m.017ym9|m.059s8|

119653|m.0jl0r_0|m.02p8px5|
119654|m.0jl0r_0|m.0f5wwn|
```

---

## 4. Question

The values in `id_destination` will in turn become `id_source`. My question is how far can I go deep in the database in order to retrieve all the relations.

For example for `m.06w4why` I want to retrieve all the relations that start from `m.01x73`, `m.0rg75` and `m.0rg9n` and combine them together.

---

## Note

It's a very hard question I think. So please le me know if it's unclear. And it wayyy beyond my reach lol

thank you.

Comment: This page may get your started and give additional information to any answers you get here : https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: yes seems really interesting thank you @MatBailie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a table `sources` with a column `id`.
The query to get the destinations for *these particular* sources would be as follows:

```
SELECT id_destination
FROM relation_entite
JOIN sources ON relation_entite.id_source = sources.id;
```

Then just plug this into a CTE, to get the basic [recursive CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) for searching a subtree:

```
WITH RECURSIVE ids(id) AS (
  VALUES('m.06w4why')                -- start with this record
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id_destination              -- get destinations for any previous sources
  FROM relation_entite
  JOIN ids ON relation_entite.id_source = ids.id
)
SELECT id FROM ids;
```

(If it is possible that there are loops in the data, you must use UNION instead of UNION ALL.)

Comment: thank you @CL. It's really amazing. I was thinking of constructing a graph by using the results of the query. Really Interesting solution. Thanks a lot.

I didn't understand well What did you mean by **loops**? meaning I can go back to `'m.06w4why'` ? from a destination?

Comment: If wiki articale A refers to B, and B refers back to A, you get an infinite loop.